# Import Postgresql Array into Solr Field

Tags: postgresql, solr, dataimporthandler

I recently ran into a problem while trying to import Data from Postgres into solr:
In Postgres, i have an array with some values in it. I would like to import all values from those array into one field in Solr, using the DataImportHandler. I know a solution like this one works:

```
  <document name="doc">
    <entity name="doc" query="SELECT id, col1, col2 FROM table;">
      <field column="id" name="id" />
      <field column="col1" name="field1" />
      <field column="col2" name="field2" />
      <entity name="array" query="SELECT UNNEST(array_col) as arr FROM table WHERE id=${doc.id};">
        <field column="arr" name="array_field">
      </entity>
    </entity>
  </document>
```

The question i have is just: Is there a more direct way of importing Postgresql-Arrays into solr, because above solution is obviously slow to import if you have to search in the table you want to import for each single line you import.

Greetings
Kai Dannies